# Why doesn't C++ support covariance in STL containers like C# or Java?

Tags: java, c#, c++, templates, collections

The [Covariance and Contravariance feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) is well supported in C# and Java collections. However C++ doesn't support them in their STL containers. Why is it so?

For example the below code will compile in C# and Java but not in C++. (The syntax will have to be translated to the specific language though)

```
class Base
{

};

class Child : public Base
{

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> baseArray;
    std::vector<Child*> ChildArray;

    baseArray = ChildArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C# counterpart of `std::vector` is `List<T>` which is invariant so your example would not compile.

Comment: The question of "why does language X not support feature Y?" is vague and not answerable. Language designers are not required to provide an explanation for why they did *not* do work that you happen to think they ought to have done, any more than you are required to provide explanations for "why not" questions I could ask you, like "why do you not live on a farm in France?" or "why did you not buy a car on January 3rd of last year?" You can clarify the question by phrasing it as a "what" question.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree to your argument but with due respect disagree to your conclusion. To a question "why do you not live on a farm in France?", a fairly acceptable answer could be "coz i can't afford it there" but it may not be agreeable to say that "coz the moon is blue" :)

Comment: With this question, I am trying to understand 2 things actually: 1) Is it not possible to implement it in C++ due to the design of the language or it was just  that the language designers thought to leave it aside for now? 2) How does C++ solve the problem that covariance is meant to solve?

Comment: That's exactly the kind of clarification that makes the question less vague and more answerable. Also it is interesting to note that C++ does implement *virtual method return type covariance*, which C# does not implement; you might be interested in exploring what design factors led to that arguable decision.

Comment: @EricLippert: If you don't mind, could you elaborate little more on the `virtual method return type covariance` and may be could you move that to an answer instead

Comment: Sure. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A88656+return+type+covariance for SO answers, or if you are interested in how we designed covariance in C# see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/page/3/ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/page/2/ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/page/1/

Comment: Those cover the issues from the perspective of the designers of C#. If you want the perspectives of the designers of C++, you'll have to ask them; all I could do is make guesses on their behalf.

Answer (score 12):

The reason is the underlying object and memory models.

To simplify the reasoning:

- In java and C#, objects of a class are [managed by reference](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-assigning-object-reference/). Containers do not store directly the object value but a reference that says where to find the value. It is therefore technically easy to mix objects of different types in the same container (polymorphism) or to use the container for objects of covariant types. The only constraint is the language semantics. This facilitates significantly the implementation of covariant containers.
- In C++,  objects are managed by value, following the rules of its memory model, which basically requires that objects of a given type a stored within a fixed size (which of course can contain pointers to elements having a dynamic size).  A container therefore has to know the type of its objects at compile-time. Unfortunately (or not) C++ also allows for separate compilation. So when you compile a container for `Animals` in one translation unit, the compiler might not know the size of a `Cat` (which might not even yet be developed). All this makes it extremely difficult to implement covariance in the language.

Interestingly, in C# you can have objects that are managed by value (in the case of a struct).  But as this [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/3723423) explain, variance only applies to reference types.

Of course, all this is simplified explanations and language-lawyers could argue on some details, but i hope it helps to grasp the idea.

Comment: The optimism is that C++11 makes it possible to create containers that allow some static and dynamic casting during assignments and transfers. [This article](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2015/11/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c.html) outlines the knowledge and techniques needed to create such containers. Of course it requires items to be stored via a reference type. An actual implementation may not be as efficient as a standard vector that stores data by value (it will be heavier in number of memory allocations) but it will make some programming tasks easier.

Comment: @rwong thank you for sharing this interesting article! Indeed, the use of containers of smart pointers is a common practice when a polymorphism is required. It is a powerful workaround for the missing covariance. Nevertheless not so easy to use as native language support.

Comment: @Christophe: So by this, containers when used with pointers or reference types can be implemented to allow covariance in C++ as well for polymorphic reasons, right?

Comment: @Sisir yes ! It is not true covariance with native support, but you could emulate covariannce keeping the base class (pointer) for the type and downcasting elements (dynamically in order to detect inconsistencies).

Comment: Like you said, C# doesn't support variance for value types, only for reference type. Similarly, couldn't C++ have supported variance only for pointer types?

Comment: @svick this is indeed a valid remark. I'd love it and who knows what C++27 will give us ;-) Meanwhile,I think there are some technical difficulties to overcome. For example: a smart pointer behaves like a pointer but is not a simple pointer and would not benefit from the improvement.  Raw pointers would be easier to tackle, but would lack the automatic memory management (and who wants raw pointers after getting used to smart ones?).  Furthermore, it may make template type deduction and overloading mechanisms work differently with the risk of breaking some existing code.

Comment: @svick C++ *does* support variance for pointer types and reference types. `std::vector<Base *>` *isn't* a pointer or reference type. You *can* write a `MyVector` such that `MyVector<Base *> bases; MyVector<Child *> children; bases = children;` copies the contents, and that's fine because you can't add an `OtherChild *` into `children` via `bases`, because they remain distinct objects

Comment: @Caleth Copying is not variance. And I'm aware `std::vector` is not a pointer, what I'm talking about is roughly being able to convert `const std::vector<Child*>*` to `const std::vector<Base*>*`.

Answer (score 4):

C++ templates are invariant. In other words, they don't support covariance or contravariance.

So, the reason, STL containers are not covariant, is because C++ doesn't support that.

Note that `std::vector` is mutable, so it cannot be covariant anyway, it needs to be invariant, otherwise it wouldn't be type-safe.

Comment: 3 things; i know they are invariant and that's why the question is why are they invariant? Second is, even the List<T> or ArrayList<T> from C# and Java are mutable right? WHat has mutability to do with variance?

Comment: They are invariant because that's the only thing C++ supports. They can't be covariant because C++ doesn't support covariance.

Comment: @Sisir: The covariance of *arrays* in C# was introduced before generics were available; however, it's problematic. If you do `baseArray = childArray`, then you can do the assignment `baseArray[i] = instanceOfBase` (where `instanceOfBase` is *not* an instance of `Child`), and crash your program (see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/).

Comment: @Sisir: (With IEnumerable<T>, for example, it's not a problem, because enumerable interface is read-only).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Why is it not problematic with `IEnumerable<T>`? `IEnumerable<object> items = new object[] {'c', "item", 5, 6.7 };` is still valid, right?

Comment: @Sisir: "WHat has mutability to do with variance?" – Umm … everything? At least, when talking about collections. Read-only collections can be covariant, write-only collections can be contravariant, mutable collections must be invariant because neither covariance nor contravariance are type-safe.

Comment: @Sisir: `object[]` implements ("is-an") `IEnumerable<object>`, so no trouble there, the underlying array is an `object` array. The problem arises when you assign something like `string[]` to `object[]` - then, you are treating it as an `object[]` array, but "under the hood", the actual variable is an array of strings; if you then try to assign, say, an integer to some array slot (which an `object[]` lets you do), there will be a type mismatch, because it expects a string.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Still why will that be a problem? I agree the array will have dissimilar objects but they all will still have to be treated equally, of their base type. May be `object` and `string` are poor examples here. But i still wont be able to call any method of child item using the `items collection` type right. Isn't that what inheritance suggests/restricts

Comment: @JörgWMittag Could you kindly elaborate a little more on this. 1 more this is there something as a `write-only collection`?

Comment: @Sisir: The problem is not that there can't be dissimilar objects in the array. It's about the requirement to adhere to the declared type (type safety). If you declare something as a `string[]`, you are explicitly saying to the compiler that that array can hold *only strings* (or, if polymorphism is involved, *only that type or its derivatives*). If you are then allowed to assign it to a variable that's of a "wider" type, like `object[]`, then you open up the possibility to break that constraint, and then why use a type-safe language in the first place?

Comment: @Sisir: With `IEnumerable<object> items = new object[] {'c', "item", 5, 6.7 };` you are already declarying the array as one that accepts any type. You can do that in C++ as well, say, with void* (or whatever the modern C++ equivalent of that is, I'm not entirely up to date). BTW: Try the C# case, you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I think the `object` type is misleading in this context. Please look at the original example mentioned in the question. Why polymorphism only? Shouldn't a base type be always replaced by a child type?

Comment: @Sisir: Ok, in terms of the original example; suppose your `Base` is `Animal`, and your `Child` is `Dog`. Then with `baseArray = ChildArray`, your *underlying* vector is a vector of `Dog`-s (it *only* works with Dogs and Dog-derived classes). But, the variable `baseArray` is, in terms of type, a vector of `Animal`-s, so now I can do: `baseArray.push_back(pCat)`, where pCat's type is a *different* child class of `Animal`.

Comment: @Sisir: "1 more this is there something as a write-only collection" – Sure: an output stream, a logger, a `Set` (if you interpret a set as its characteristic function, then you can only add items to the set and ask the set whether the item is in there, but you can't take out an item or enumerate the set).

Answer (score 3):

In Java, generics are invariant; you would need to use bounded wildcards to achieve covariance or contravariance. To do what you want, in Java it would need to be declared like this:

```
List<? extends Base> baseArray;
List<Child> childArray;
baseArray = ChildArray;
```

By using the `? extends` wildcard, Java prevents you from adding any elements other than `null` into the list using the reference of type `List<? extends Base>`, since the wildcard stands for an unknown type and you don't know that what you're adding is an instance of that type. You can only get elements out of it.

(It is true that arrays in Java are covariant, but it seems like you are talking about generic containers here, not arrays.)

C++ doesn't have bounded wildcards. The most common use case of bounded wildcards in Java is when you accept a collection parameter that the method only needs to read out of, so it doesn't really care about the exact type argument, only that the type argument is a particular type or its subtype:

```
void printListOfBase(List<? extends Base> list) {
    // you can call methods of Base on the elements of list
}
```

In C++, you can achieve the same thing with templates without needing any bound, because C++ template instantiations are "duck-typed". Unlike in Java, where a generic class or method is only compiled once and you must prove to the compiler when compiling the class/methd that what you are doing is type-safe giving the bounds, in C++, a templated class or function is compiled separately for each instantiation (i.e. each type argument used), and so the compiler can check when compiling a specific instantiation whether the type works or not, without needing bounds specified beforehand:

```
void printListOfBase<T>(std::vector<T> list) {
    // you can call methods of Base on the elements of list
    // and it will compile as long as T has such a method
}
```

As for your particular case of having a local variable of a wildcard-parameterized type, that is much less common and there is no direct equivalent for it in C++.

Answer (score 1):

In C# and Java, when you do `x = y;`<sup>1</sup>, you now have (at least) two names for the same `Object`. In C++ you still have two distinct objects, but some code ran and they presumably have the same value now.

The semantics of `baseArray = ChildArray` in C++ would be very different if it were allowed, it would be a copy operation.

You *can* copy the contents of `ChildArray` into `baseArray`, but not with `=`

```
baseArray.assign(ChildArray.begin(), ChildArray.end());
```

The `boost` library has a helper for situations like this

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

baseArray = boost::copy_range<decltype(baseArray)>(ChildArray);
```

Footnote 1: Assuming `x` and `y` aren't primitives. In that case it matches the C++ case.